# How to check if data already exists then randomly generate new data from an Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Okay so, I made an array containing 270+ different strings. The main goal is too echo out 60 strings from that array and combine them..

Ex. 1.String, 1.String2.

The 2 echo'd out strings are a combination, and should be together like 1-1 and 2-2, 3-3, and ect. In total there would be 30 combinations, but 60 strings.

Also, the way I have it is the first generated string should be combo'd with the 31st string generated

I was able to do this using a for loop, but now I had to use a mysql database to check if that combination already exists, then tell the random operator to generate another combination, until it finds a combination that doesn't already exist in the table. Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
$input = array("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", "ITEM5"); //There are 273 items in the list
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 60);
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $name_db);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 29; $i++) {

        $check = "SELECT * FROM contest WHERE name1 = '$input[$rand_keys[$i]]' AND name2 = '$input[$rand_keys[$i+30]]'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if ($data[$i] > 1) {

            //This combination already exists generate a new one until it generates one that doesn't exist
            while ($data[$i] > 1) {

                $rand_keys2 = array_rand($input, 2);
                $input[$rand_keys2[0]] = $input[$rand_keys[$i]];
                $input[$rand_keys2[1]] = $input[$rand_keys[$i + 30]];
            }
            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i]];
            echo '-';
            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i + 30]];
        } else {

            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i]];
            echo '-';
            echo $input[$rand_keys[$i + 30]];
        }
    }
```

That is all I have so far, I'm pretty sure my error is in the mysql statement could anyone fix that for me, and there is probably a bunch of mistakes in the rest of it. I'm just beginning, so don't mind some noob mistakes if you see them. Btw, when I run it, it just comes to a blank page.

Comment: If you think there's an error in your query, then use `$rs = mysqli_query($con, $check) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: *"Btw, when I run it, it just comes to a blank page."* - That is usually associated with syntax errors but you're not checking for them, nor displaying them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've added that and still it displays nothing, just a blank white page.

Comment: `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` does that output anything? and use `var_dump();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nope, the Hello World doesn't output anything either.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay, it seems as if I have a syntax error on this line  $check = "SELECT * FROM contest WHERE name1 = '$input[$rand_keys[$i]]' AND name2 = '$input[$rand_keys[$i+30]]'"; It says ........ unexpected: '['...... expected: ']'

Comment: ok well there's only 2 possibilities here. You're not running as `.php` extension, or your server's not setup to parse PHP.

Comment: then it must be your PHP version. which one is it? if it's less than 5.4, you will need to use `array()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's PHP 5.4. Here is what it looks like on netbeans http://gyazo.com/19c766483c6c7bfe25e05a2786831316.....If you see after the second ']' after the $rand_keys, it's orange and not black. Why is that?

Comment: Don't **EVER** try to get php array data from within a string!!!! `'$input[$rand_keys[$i]]'` should be `'".$input[$rand_keys[$i]]."'` OR `'{$input[$rand_keys[$i]]}'`

Comment: lordie, wish I could say now. Try escaping your data, there may be characters that MySQL's kicking about, or try `WHERE name1 = '{$input[$rand_keys[$i]]}'` or `WHERE name1 = '".$input[$rand_keys[$i]]."'` etc... for the other one.  I'm at a dead end here, sorry. Edit: Seems that @Twister1002 had the same idea as I did; we were typing it out at the same time lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it's displaying data now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Let @Twister1002 submit an answer to close the question with and you can accept it. They have my blessing, *cheers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, **NEVER** try to get data from an array within quotes! Always do it outside of quotes; especially in multi-denominational arrays.

`'$input[$rand_keys[$i]]'` should be rewritten as `'".$input[$rand_keys[$i]]."'` OR `'{$input[$rand_keys[$i]]}'`.

In my opinion it is better to do it outside of quotes instead of using  `{ }`.

Comment: I appreciate it @Fred-ii-. You were basically on the right track. When I saw this question though, my first thought was that array inside the quotes.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad this one got resolved. I was running out of ideas lol *Cheers*